# does retrieve data from cache will be count as Read Operation in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want my app to fetch data from my server only once in every one hour. so if the timestamp is over one hour, then I use `Source.SERVER` to retrieve data from firestore server, otherwise, if it is below range of one hour, then just get previous data from cache using `Source.CACHE`

so my question is, if I get the data from `Source.CACHE`, will it be counted as Read operation in Firestore ?

currently I am investigating the number of read operation in firestore, because in my project, the number of reads is way above the expected number. so I suspect this cache is the problem, because I now assume the data from cache will also be counted as read operation. am I right ?

I have no other idea why the number of read is so high in my project.

Comment: "I have no other idea why the number of read is so high in my project." The typical cause is that developers don't know (or forget) that reads performed by the Firebase console are also charged.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thats exactly my problem. I didn't know that accessing database from firebase dashboard will also perform read operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documents read from cache are not billed as reads.